# Debugging the remember me in my symfony 6 application

Tags: symfony, session

My remember function for my symfony application seems to be not working appropriately. I've followed the resource provided by Symfony itself [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html).

Anyway, here is part of my `security.yaml` file:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: /p/login
            entry_point: form_login
            # login_throttling:
            #     limiter: app.custom.limiter
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            switch_user: true
            custom_authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                token_provider:
                    doctrine: true
```

My `LoginFormAuthenticator.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\RememberMeBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;
use Symfony\Component\RateLimiter\RateLimiterFactory;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordHasherInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $email = $request->request->get('email');
        $password = $request->request->get('password');
        $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($password),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $csrfToken),
                new RememberMeBadge()
            ],
        );
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Invalid credentials.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $providerKey): ?Response
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('feed', ['page_num' => 1]));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('login'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}
```

The database schema that was created by using the doctrine as the token provider:

[image]

The user gets logged in but then logs out automatically after an hour (I believe) which has gotten annoying. Even though 1 week has been specified in the `security.yaml` file.

---

**UPDATE**
After reading threads via github ([here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28314)), it seems this approach isn't viable. What alternative should we use to allow our users to stay logged in within the specified duration that we note in our `security.yaml` file?

Consider that if we use cookies or regular sessions for user log ins, every user will be logged out every time we deploy because of the `cache:clear` function.

Comment: Did you add the [checkbox](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html#activating-the-remember-me-system) to the login form? Or try the `always_remember_me: true`? Are entries being added to the db with the correct date?

Comment: Yes, the checkbox is part of the login form. The date looks correct. I didnt turn on always remember me because thats not something we wanted to do.

Comment: I also confirmed within the debug that when the checkbox is checked, it shows as "on" and that the RememberMeBadge is showing in the authenticator. Hmmmm'

Comment: Have you tried cookie based instead of db based? Just for debugging.. I did see an [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28314) posted but it was a while ago, could still be a bug?

Comment: Do you have a `REMEMBERME` cookie after you log in with the checkbox checked? Is your checkbox name exactly `_remember_me`?

Comment: @Bossman It could possibly be this because that's the only reason I can think of for this. Our production server is the ONLY server that gets multiple requests while local and staging do not (those places login sessions are kept in tact). Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @JulienB. Yes, to both of those.

Comment: @Bossman also it seems that if I change `lazy:true` to `lazy:false` it fixes the issue? So maybe I need to do that?

Comment: @Majo0od, the last comment on the issue mentions that too..

Comment: I've tried this and it didn't fix anything. Still require help on this.

Comment: *"auto log out users every time we deploy."* reading this in the bounty reason is an important clue. Does the deploy process regenerate a new secret (`kernel.secret` parameter or `APP_SECRET` env var)? Remember me cookies are signed by this secret, so changing this secret automatically invalidates all remember me cookies.

Comment: It doesn’t. Clear cache seems to be auto logging people out

Comment: @WouterJ what happens if .env is re-uploaded every time (but the kernel.secret doesnt change)?

Comment: How do you use Session? By default Symfony stores it in files, have you tried using database? I can't remember if cache:clear does something to session files (event if they are inside cache folders). Try it if you dont have a better idea.
 https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/database.html#store-sessions-in-a-relational-database-mariadb-mysql-postgresql

Comment: Can you please read the thread above this comment. It's all about how the database session is bugged.

Comment: Also my entire question is about how the DB session expires after 1 hour

Answer (score -1):

Goto user entity and find `getUserIdentyfier()` function. Make sure this returns email.

Property: email<

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).